# Does the source of excess calories affect the nutritional quality of the body's fat stores?

Tags: nutrition, calories, body-fat

I've just eaten 3500 calories over maintenance (and for simplicity's sake, I don't excersice so none of this will go to muscle mass). Now I will gain one pound of fat. But let's consider two different scenarios:

- I eat 3500 excess calories worth of Oreos
- I eat 3500 excess calories worth of vegetables

Either way, I will gain one pound of fat. But will the quality of that fat be higher if I gain it from vegetables rather than Oreos? In the future, if I eat 3500 calories under maintenance and my body uses my fat stores, will fat stores which were developed from vegetables be healthier and more nutritionally dense?

Or does the body use up all micronutrients and macronutrients at the time of ingestion, making all fat stores equal?

Note that this question can apply to both macronutrients and macronutrients (e.g. excess calories from carbs rather than fat, etc.)

Comment: there are multiple types of fat.. subcutaneous fat, visceral fat, intramuscular fat. 3500 calories from oreos will more likely go to subcutaneous fat which is primarily stubborn fat on your belly and your love handles etc.. as opposed to visceral or intramuscular fat. this fat is hard to lose even with dieting, and less healthy for the body to have. with the oreos youll also be getting into blood sugar spikes, insulin resistance, and weight gain from that. 3500 calories vegetables is the way to go as itll be healthier fat. the fiber will help as well. wish i could type more